# Should package.json be blocked by web server (IIS)

Tags: asp.net, json, iis, package.json, http-error

If I try to access `web.config` server returns `HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found` (The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.)

If I try to access `packages.config` server returns `HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found` (The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.)

Now I get why those two are blocked/filtered. But I am not sure why package.json is not.

1. Could somebody explain the reason for it?
2. If it should be blocked how do I go about it, so it does not affect other `.json` files that do need be served by the Web Server (IIS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it to web.config's hiddenSegments section:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="package.json" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

More details about hiddenSegments available [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments)

Comment: Great. You think this would be something that is part of their documentation. Anyway, maybe the question was to trivial, but I was amazed that I could not find anything online about.